# Shiv'a Ve'esrim Umatayim - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows two hundred twenty-seven?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the Posuk "אִשָּׁה כִּי תַזְרִיעַ וְיָלְדָה זָכָר" the Baal HaTurim says that the gematria of זכר is ברכה.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't looked for the source, but the *K'li Yakar* [is quoted](http://books.google.com/books?id=PQV_H4nHWEMC&pg=PA423&dq=hundred) as having said that the difference between forgetting (*shachach* = 328) and remembering (*zachar* = **227**) is the 101 times one must review Torah.

Answer (score 1):

[*Ramban* to *Sh'mos* 12:40](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14126&pgnum=174) discusses the Jews' being in Egypt for 227 years.

Answer (score -1):

A [Marla Gibbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marla_Gibbs) (of "[The Jeffersons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Jeffersons)" fame) [vehicle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/227_%28TV_series%29).

Comment: Aww, am I supposed to somehow intuit why I got the downvotes?